# Inno Setup Components list use wrong colors

Tags: inno-setup

[image]

How to change the txt color of the components option text? For a strange reason the selected components become white which is difficult to read under gray background.

Script code sample

```
[Setup]

VersionInfoVersion=1
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyComp\MyApp
AppName=myapp       
AppVerName=App
DefaultGroupName=MyApp
OutputBaseFilename=MyApp_v1_setup
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
WizardImageFile=setup_inno.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=setup_inno_small.bmp
OutputDir=.\OutputSetup
LanguageDetectionMethod=locale
PrivilegesRequired=admin


[Files]

Source: "./Binaries/MyApp.Exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; CopyMode: alwaysskipifsameorolder; Components: My_App;


[Languages]
Name: "gr"; MessagesFile: "Greek.isl"
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"


[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "full";
Name: "custom"; Description: "custom"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "My_App"; Description: "component 1"; Types: full custom;
Name: "DirectX"; Description: "component 2"; Types: full custom;
```

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: I am using Win7 64Bit, but give me some time to isolate some parts of the code i am using and i will give you either the solution or the problematic piece of code.

Comment: I left only the very basic script code and the problem is still there. You can check the code uploaded.Is that a bug or something ? I am using version 5.5.9(a)

Comment: Works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6D6Ug.png Inno Setup 5.5.9(a) on Windows 7 64-bit. Of course, I do not have your `WizardImageFile`, `WizardSmallImageFile` and `MyApp.Exe`. Though I doubt that matters. What theme do you have in Windows?

Comment: Btw, do not use Ansi version of Inno Setup. It's provided for backward compatibility purposes only. Use Unicode version.

Comment: Strange... I reverted to original windows aero theme, but this is not solved the problem. I will install the unicode version but I doubt that if this is the problem....

Comment: No, the Unicode version won't solve the problem. But you should develop Unicode-enabled applications only nowadays.

Comment: Good news, unicode version solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Installation of the unicode version solved the problem.